# Como eliminar el espacio entre div que vscode pone automáticamente

Tags: vscode, div

Necesito saber cómo evitar que el VS Code me inserté un espacio automático después de mis div al guardar el archivo.
La idea es que los div salgan en línea unidos(sin espacio entre ellos)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      body, html {
        min-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font: Arial 14px;
      }
      div{
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        background:blue;
        display: inline-block;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box1"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

PD:En Notepad++ si me deja guardar los div uno detrás del otro en la misma línea y con eso eliminó el espacio entre ellos en el navegador. Pero quiero saber cómo hacer lo mismo en el VS Code

Comment: No veo que tiene que ver el editor de código con el problema expuesto

Comment: *elimino el espacio entre ellos en el navegador*. Eso no me queda para nada claro ¿cuál espacio? Hablamos de elementos `HTML`, no de texto, lo mismo los puedes ubicar uno encima de otro con un par de reglas CSS y lo del *espacio entre ellos* no tendría ningún sentido. ¿Puedes explicarte mejor? Saludos

Comment: Cuando el código de arriba se abre en un navegador, los div salen uno al lado del otro pero con un espacio vacío en el medio. Si en el notepad++ se ponen esos div uno detrás de otro en la misma línea y sin espacio entre ellos, al guardar y abrir en el navegador los cuadrado(div) salen todos unidos sin espacio entre ellos. Por el contrario si con el VS Code pones los div consecutivamente uno detrás de otro en la misma línea, al guardar, el VS Code los pone automáticamente uno debajo de otro. Es esto último lo que no se como evitar.